# Cannot save edited theme PHP pages in WordPress editor (Admin panel)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-hosting, custom-wordpress-pages

I am unable to Save the main theme (PHP) files using the WordPress editor. I get the following error:

> Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the
>   PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change
>   by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

[image]

I have cleared my browser cache, website cache, de-activated all plugins and reinstalled the main theme.

I have also checked my permissions and ownership of all files on the server. No issues their, 
However, My other sites can edit and save on this server.

Comment: Do you have error logging enabled?

Comment: Which one, error logging?

Answer (score 0):

Please refresh and try to make changes . If not plz update all the http site links to https.

Answer (score 0):

Error is coming from file wp-admin/includes/file.php
It exits 2 tests, 1 with :
`$r = wp_remote_get( $url, compact( 'cookies', 'headers', 'timeout', 'sslverify' ) );`
and the other only:
`$r = wp_remote_get( $url, compact( 'cookies', 'headers', 'timeout' ) );`

Just add `, 'sslverify'` in the second after time out and you should be able to push your files :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced that issue just now. Then, i tried update syntax through web hosting service. In my case is cPanel. Use file manager to find file inside theme folder you want to update. E.g `public_html/wp-content/themes/astra/functions.php`